# The break statement doesn't work until the loop repeats twice

Tags: c++

```
for (inputNum != 0; counter < 9; counter++)
{
//if (inputNum == 0)break;
scanf("%f\n", &inputNum);
if(inputNum == 0){break;}
inputArray[counter] = inputNum;
// if (inputNum == 0) {break;}
//break;
}
```

Just running into this issue, have no idea how else to explain it. Issue is the title.

Comment: `for ( inputNum != 0; ...` makes no sense.

Comment: That's a pretty funky `for` statement.

Comment: People have been far too hard on this post. Granted the code is quite messy but if you fix up the program and run it you will see the problem the OP posted about has nothing to do with his messy for loop. In fact the cause is quite subtle.

Comment: @Serdalis the problem may be real and legitimate, but the _question_ as it currently stands could still be considered "unclear" or "not useful" even if the answer is, admittedly, interesting.

Answer (score 0):

To start of with, the syntax for your for loop, well, it's strange, and not clear.

```
for ( inputNum != 0; ...
```

this doesn't make any logical sense, and will fail the code. If this is really what you wanted to do then !( inputNum = 0) will correct the syntax. Otherwise it doesn't work.

And your if statement inside, oh god. You have to INDENT. And It makes no sense. Please make an effort to learn the code, and try not to just ask "My code doesn't work, fix it pl0x."

Answer (score 0):

Your "for" statement is constructed incorrectly. The first part of the for statement doesn't perform any testing--it is called prior to the for statement being executed, but not again. [Good reference here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/).

It looks like you want to read while inputNum is not 0, and your counter<9 (are you reading at most 9 numbers?)

```
for(/* no initialization here*/; inputNum != 0 && counter < 9; counter++) {
    scanf("%f\n", &inputNum);
    //  if(inputNum == 0){break;},
    //  ^~~~ not needed because scanf and the condition
    // inputNum != 0 will quit the loop.
}
```

Seeing an empty initializer in a "for" statement is kinda weird, but still legal. In fact, for(;;) is also legal, but creates an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code appears to only work on the second loop is due to your `scanf` function.

```
scanf("%f\n", &inputNum);
```

If you changed this to (correctly) be:

```
scanf("%f", &inputNum);
```

You'll notice that your code executes correctly.
This is because scanf is blocking untill the second number is entered.

This is because the `\n` at the end of the format string is eating up all subsequent `\n`  (and other white-space characters) entered into the stream.

Entering any non-whitespace charactor and then pressing enter again will allow the `scanf` to terminate since it will no longer be consumed.

Quoting from [IBM scanf](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur%2Fgtpc2%2Fcpp_fscanf-scanf-sscanf.html) (emphasis mine):

> White-space characters, as specified by the isspace function, such as blanks and new-line characters. **A white-space character causes the fscanf, scanf, and sscanf functions to read, but not store, all consecutive white-space characters in the input up to the next character that is not a white-space character.** One white-space character in format matches any combination of white-space characters in the input.